# Unable to start lxc container with -f

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lxc, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to migrate some lxc containers from lxc 1.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 to lxc 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. Our scripts don't ever call `lxc-create`, but invoke the containers directly with `lxc-start` and a custom config file:

```
lxc-start -d --name mongo -f ~/.containers/containers/mongo.conf
```

This command works just fine on Ubuntu 14.04, but when I run them on 16.04 I get the error message `Error: container mongo is not defined`.

I could run `lxc-create` beforehand, but this seems like an unnecessary step, especially since we already have custom filesystems created for all of our containers. Can anyone tell me how to avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Anyone knows what the problem is?